# Switching between Platform-Configurations breaks COM-Compatibility

Tags: visual-studio-2008, com

I have an rather odd problem with Visual Studio once more. I have a library which depends on one COM-Library. Out of the blue the COM-Library depending on MDAC 2.7 suddenly<sup>1</sup> produced this Compile-Error:

```
Error loading type library/DLL. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80029C4A (TYPE_E_CANTLOADLIBRARY))
```

Together with this error others showed up that Properties were not found on the designated object. After much investigation into my system, I could figure out that for some reason some MDAC libraries were not registered anymore<sup>2</sup>. Registering them by hand (because the setup wouldn't let me reinstall it anymore) fixed the error, but the errors about the not found Properties stayed. It boiled down to this:

```
Me.prv_comObject.Value = aValuePassedIn ' This throws the error that the
                                          Property "Value" could not be found '

' This works instead: '
Me.prv_comObject.set_Value(aValuePassedIn)
```

Now comes the clue, this only breaks in `x86` configuration, in `Any CPU` I can still use the Properties. I was also unable to reproduce this with SharpDevelop, SD is always expecting Properties. I'm also not sure if this is related to the MDDAC-Thingy in any way.

It's a VB.NET project, the COM Library is VB6 and OS is Windows XP. Any ideas what might cause this behavior?

<sup>1</sup>: Yes, suddenly. I was normally developing, then switched to `Release` mode and then it was there and wouldn't go away anymore.

<sup>2</sup>: Yes, I was messing around with MDAC, because I tried to help pinpoint the problem which was [now introduced with Windows 7 SP1](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/windowsgeneraldevelopmentissues/thread/3a4ce946-effa-4f77-98a6-34f11c6b5a13) (yes, we were unaware of that). But I did not mess around the registration of the MDAC libraries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After three days of wondering what that is, it is gone.

I've cleaned up the projects, removed the `obj` and `bin` and suddenly everything turned back to normal. Seems like the object files were corrupted.